# What is "を " used for when not attached to a verb at the end of a sentence?

Tags: particle-を

In the song, he says "君の中に落としたひとりを" and I know hitori is "一人" but it's not a verb, yet it's at the end of a sentence:

> また隠した もう一つの夢の中で見てた夜を思い出した
>   君の中に落としたひとりを
>   見つけないで 僕はまだいないから

Is it used because he's a male like putting "da" at the end of a sentence? I'm translating it as "Inside you I dropped..." but then the rest doesn't make sense with "alone". What does を mean here?

- The song is "White Silence" by TK*

Comment: Please edit your question to include some context, the name of the song, and so forth.

Comment: I think you may have misidentified the end of the sentence.

Comment: I think it ties in with the next line: [見つけないで 僕はまだいないから](https://www.musixmatch.com/ja/lyrics/TK-from-%E5%87%9B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E6%99%82%E9%9B%A8/white-silence#)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence did not end with を.

Instead of reading it as (～ひとりを), it should be read as (～)を見つけないで which means "don't look for ～"